# How to silent http error responses on Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, http

How can i avoid having http error responses logged in the browser console. An example: I have an app on angular, if you are not authenticated you'll be redirected and get a unauthorised error (401) response from the API logged on console. This doesn't happen on big applications, if you are not authenticated  you will just get redirected to the login page and no error will be logged on console, how do they do that ?

Comment: Unless you are doing some logging yourself in error callbacks then browser itself will show you `401` in console and you can turn those off in some dev tools like firebug but otherwise nothing you can do with them. They are built in behavior

Answer (score 0):

> if you are not authenticated you will just get redirected to the login page and no error will be logged on console, how do they do that ?

You may need to look at using $http.interceptors - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Basically you would set up a *responseError* interceptor to redirect to or show the login UI.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {

    'responseError': function(rejection) {
        if (notAthenticated){ return ...do login logic... }
        else { return $q.reject(rejection) }
    }
  };
});
```